# Unique pair of 3 or more array in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array like

```
main['device']=['iphone4','iphone5','iphone6'];
main['color']=['red','blue','white'];
main['size']=['10','20','30'];
```

All 3 arrays. are dynamic.
I need all combination like

```
iphone4 red 10
iphone4 red 20
iphone4 red 30
iphone4 blue 10
iphone4 blue 10
iphone4 blue 30
iphone4 white 10
iphone4 white 30
iphone4 white 30


iphone5 red 10
iphone5 red 20
iphone5 red 30
iphone5 blue 10
iphone5 blue 10
iphone5 blue 30
iphone5 white 10
iphone5 white 30
iphone5 white 30


iphone6 red 10
iphone6 red 20
iphone6 red 30
iphone6 blue 10
iphone6 blue 10
iphone6 blue 30
iphone6 white 10
iphone6 white 30
iphone6 white 30
```

JavaScript or jquery solution if possible.
All combination need to be unique and need to  print same way.

Comment: What is the problem with the code you currently have to do this?

Comment: is that irregularity in blue and white a typo..? otherwise a 3 nested `forEach()` would do it straight...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pure JavaScript solution:

```js
var main = new Array([]);
    
main['device']=['iphone4','iphone5','iphone6'];
main['color']=['red','blue','white'];
main['size']=['10','20','30'];

var res = [];
main['device'].forEach(function (device) {
  main['color'].forEach(function(color) {
    main['size'].forEach(function(size) {
      res.push([device, color, size].join(' '));
    })
  });
  res.push('');
});


document.body.innerHTML = res.join('<br>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code you want. I hope it helps.

```js
    var main = new Array([]);
    
     main['device']=['iphone4','iphone5','iphone6'];
     main['color']=['red','blue','white'];
     main['size']=['10','20','30'];
    
    $.each(main['device'], function(index, value){
      var device = value;
      $.each(main['color'], function(index2, value2) {
        var color = value2;
        $.each(main['size'], function(index3, value3) {
           var size = value3;
           var res = value + " " + value2 + " " + value3;
           $('#res').append(res);
           $('#res').append('<br/>');
        })
        
      })
      $('#res').append('<br/>');
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="res"></div>
```